# Android fill Spinner from Database takes old entries

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-spinner

At the start of my App i show a Dialog.
In this dialog I have 2 spinners. If I change the entry of the first spinner the app loads a JSON file and parses it into a database. Then the spinner gets filled with a SimpleCursorAdapter from the database where the JSON file was saved. The problem is that when I change the first spinner it always loads the database which was saved the last time the spinner was changed.

Here's my code from the onItemSelected method:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        dialogs.dismiss();
    }
};
Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        klassenListeAktualisieren((new Long(txtBerufID)).toString());
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
};
checkUpdate.start();
dbHelperKlasse = new KlassenlisteDbAdapter(myContext);
dbHelperKlasse.open();

Cursor cursor_Names = dbHelperKlasse.fetchAllOfThem();
startManagingCursor(cursor_Names);

String[] columns = new String[] { dbHelperKlasse.KEY_TITLE };
int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(myContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cursor_Names, columns, to);
mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
klassenSpinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Let me know if you need to know anything else (Code etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For everybody who faces the same problem here's the solution:

Create a new method where you put in your fetch call to the database and where you populate your spinner.

Afterwards, in the `handleMessage()` method of your `Handler` (where I closed my `Dialog`), call this method. So the spinner gets filled **after** he wrote into the database and not **during** this process (and then showing the "old" data from the database).

Comment: +1 for coming back and providing the solution. Always appreciated.

Comment: But please ACCEPT it as the solution :) (Click the tick)

Comment: @Basiclife I couldn't until now since 6 hours didn't pass by... But i will... in Exactly 6 minutes :)

Comment: @user754730 My apologies, hadn't realised you were inside the timeout.